# Undefined index: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] Openshift scalable app

Tags: php, openshift, http-host

I have an scalable app in openshift and I'm having problems trying to access the PHP `$_SERVER` variables.

I am just trying to do "`$domain = str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`" but got the error

> undefined index HTTP_HOST

, this works fine in a normal app, but not in the scalable one.

My app have two main folders "frontend" and "backend" and I redirect all the data from the root folder to "frontend" with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule    ^$    frontend/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) frontend/$1    [L]
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this error? Thanks

**UPDATE**: Just figured out that openshift has a bot that check the health of the application every two or three seconds, those access from the bot were causing the errors.

Comment: When I finally looked carefully at the request log, I saw clearly that OpenShift's app monitors were making requests with HTTP/1.0. That was the final bit of information that helped me understand what was going on. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If HTTP_HOST is missing it either means the (a) the client is using a very old browser, (b) the bot doesn't send it or (c) the site is being accessed by it's IP Address rather than the domain name.

The manual implies this index may not always be set
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

if `HTTP_HOST` is missing it means that your application uses `CLI` to run.